# Unable to return correct value of a variable in a recursive function

Tags: c, function, recursion, return, factorial

I am making following program to find factorial of a given number recursively.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int fact1=1;

int recursion(int x)
{
    if(x==0)
    {
        return fact1;
    }

    fact1=fact1*x;
    x--;
    recursion(x);   
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d",recursion(5));
    return (0); 
}
```

**Problem :**

The problem is that whenever I run this program it always gives me some garbage value 22752240 .

Thus Inorder to test my recursion I placed `printf("%d",fact1)` in the recursive function to check whether `fact1` was 120 before being returned

```
int recursion(int x)
{
    if(x==0)
    {
        printf("%d",fact1);
        return fact1;
    }

    fact1=fact1*x;
    x--;
    recursion(x);   
}
```

and when I executed program I got this 120 22752240 as output, meaning that `recursion()` was printing correct value of `fact1` but was unable to return correct value of `fact1`.

Can anyone explain why is this happening?

Comment: return recursion(x);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. you forgot to `return` a value at the very the end of `recursion()`. Without that `return` statement, the use of `recursion()` as an argument ot `printf()` invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To elaborate, only for the case when `x == 0` is TRUE, you're using a `return` statement to return a value. In other scenario, you're missing a `return` statement. You need to add `return` statement for other case also.

Reference: Form `C11` standard, chapter §6.9.1, *Function definitions*

> If the `}` that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.

That said, the recommended signature of `main()` is `int main(void)`.

Comment: can u please tell tell exactly where are u recommending to add `return fact1`

Comment: @varunsinghal65 I guess, a `return recursion(x);` at the end will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to return something in the case `x!=0`, so garbage was returned. Modify the last line of your function as the following:

```
return recursion(x);
```

This will return the value computed by the recursive call.

Answer (score 0):

The function needs to return a value on each path, anything else is undefined.
What you're seeing printed is whatever value was stored in the place where your function's return value should have been stored.

But globals and recursion don't go well together - your function should only care about its parameters and the return value.

If you follow the definition of the factorial, you hardly need to think about the code:

- `factorial(0)` is 1
- `factorial(x)` is `x` multiplied with `factorial(x - 1)`

In code:

```
int factorial(int x)
{
    if (x == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return x * factorial(x - 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
It is because when x becomes 0 and return statement works at that time it return value of fact to the function call recursion(1) called via recursion function not to the function call recursion(5) called from main. so the value of fact at last recursion is 120 but it is not returned to main properly.



u can do it by ommiting using fact variable

int recursion(int x)
{
    if(x==0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return x*recursion(--x);
    }   
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d",recursion(5));
    return (0); 
}
```

Comment: Please improve your answer by using correct formatting and writing words entirely (for example **you** instead of **u**).

Comment: i am new here thats why i am having this problem. Now i will take care of this. Thanks for pointing it out.